# Detect failed records in Batch Apex Execute( ) Method

Tags: apex

In BatchApex, is there anyway to detect the records that have failed in EXECUTE( ) method and Send an Email in EXECUTE ( ) method itself?. I am sure of sending Email in FINISH() method. But i want to send Email in EXECUTE method itself as and when they are processed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [new option](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_platformevents.htm) available that should give you something closer to what you want:

**Firing Platform Events from Batch Apex**

You add the option as part of the declaration:

```
public with sharing class YourSampleBatchJob implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, 
   Database.RaisesPlatformEvents{ 
   // class implementation 
}
```

Once added, you need to add a listener for the events, as shown in the docs.

Key passage from docs:

> Batch Apex classes can fire platform events when encountering an error
>   or exception. Clients listening on an event can obtain actionable
>   information, such as how often the event failed and which records were
>   in scope at the time of failure. **Events are also fired for
>   Salesforce Platform internal errors and other uncatchable Apex
>   exceptions such as LimitExceptions, which are caused by reaching
>   governor limits.**
>
> An event record provides more granular error tracking than the Apex
>   Jobs UI. It includes the record IDs being processed, exception type,
>   exception message, and stack trace. You can also incorporate custom
>   handling and retry logic for failures. You can invoke custom Apex
>   logic from any trigger on this type of event, so Apex developers can
>   build functionality like custom logging or automated retry handling.

Answer (score 0):

It is always recommend to send email from finish method because if you have 100 records you will get 100 email if email code is inside execute method.

if you still want to send update your execute method with following code.

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<SObject> scope) { 
    List<Account> accountList = new List<Account>();
    for(SObject s : scope){
      Account acct = (Account) s;
      // Logic to update fields on the Account
       accountList.add(acct);
    }

    if(accountList.size() > 0) {
        //Update records
        List<Database.SaveResult> dsrs = Database.Update(accountList, false);

        for(Database.SaveResult dsr : dsrs){
            /********here you will check for failed record ******
            if(!dsr.isSuccess()){
                String errMsg = dsr.getErrors()[0].getMessage();
                /*******Send mail here************************/
            }

        }
    }
}
```